# How do I set battery charging threshold in linux on non Thinkpad laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery

I know that charging battery near 100% is bad.
However, a charging threshold can be set by using `tp_smapi` or `tlp`.
Unfortunately, this package is only for Thinkpad.
How can I set this for a non-Thinkpad laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Most vendors to not expose such an API and there is not one in the Kernel, so either it's handled in hardware, or the BIOS (check for a setting there).
The reason is lithium batteries can catch on fire when changed improperly so most would consider it unwise to plug that system into something as buggy and malware prone as a modern OS, or letting end users anywhere close to it.

Comment: If there was such an API, it could take care of safety. I see no actual value in this argument (fire hazard preventing implementation of battery charge threshold for users).